# Object to arraycollection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

linedataColl is an AC that contains 100+ of rows extract from CSV, I wish to add item into SuperDataCollection object by object but the only problem was I'm unable to see any data display in "S" which is a datagrid. What wrong with my code?

```
   var superDataCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
   var dc:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
   var di:Object = new Object();
   for(var aa:int=0; aa<5;aa++){
    di.username = linedataColl[aa].username;
    di.email = linedataColl[aa].email;
    dc.addItem(di);
    superDataCollection.addItem(dc);
}
s.dataProvider = dc;
```

For my datagrid:

```
var columns:Array = [];
var myDataGridColumn:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("id");
myDataGridColumn.headerText = "ID";
myDataGridColumn.width = 40;
columns.push(myDataGridColumn);
... // so on for other column
dg1.columns = columns;
```

Answer (score 2):

I Found Two thing wrong in your code

1) Declare **di** in For loop, new instance for each iteration

```
for(var aa:int=0; aa<5;aa++){
     var di:Object = new Object();
```

2) You are not defining proper **dataField** for DataGridColumn, although you are passing **id** in constructor, but i didn't find it in upper code you share,it could be

```
di.id = aa
```

or

```
myDataGridColumn.headerText = "ID";   
myDataGridColumn.width = 40;   
myDataGridColumn.dataField = "username";
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: 1) Did you read the code correctly? 2) I thought have I put "..." with the comment stated already? I just cut it short to make the code cleaner. I not sure if your comment is meant to providing solution or to point the mistake? Confusing.

Comment: I pointed to mistakes which i saw in your code, ya you put"..." in 2nd section, but in 1st section you are not initializing "id" and also var "di" is declared out of for loop. isn't it?